# Horizontal scroll not working in iPhone ios 9

Tags: html, ios, iphone, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using a `div` with pinch zoom option, in ionic with angularjs mobile app. It is working fine on an android device, but on the iPhone (iOS 9) I'm not able move the `div` to see the content which is hidden. I'm able to move the `div` content vertically but not horizontally.I've searched for the solution and implemented the style,

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

but I've still the same issue. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by touch events.

Sample code below,

```
  $( ".pinch" ).on( "touchstart", fingerDown)
                 .on('touchend', fingerUp)
               .on('touchmove', fingerMove)
               .on('touchend', fingerend);


  var startX = 0;
  var endX = 0;
  var lastMargin = 0;
  var leftMargin = 0;

  function fingerend(e){                        
    lastMargin = leftMargin;
    leftMargin = 0;        
  }

  function fingerMove(e){        
    var tempEndX = 0;        
    var tempLeftMargin = 0;
    tempEndX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;        

    if(startX > tempEndX){
      tempLeftMargin = -(startX - tempEndX);
    }else{
      tempLeftMargin = tempEndX - startX;
    }

    tempLeftMargin = tempLeftMargin + lastMargin;
    var deltaVal = $("#my-div").children().width();
    var minVal = -(deltaVal - 280);
    var maxVal = 10;

    if(tempLeftMargin > minVal && tempLeftMargin < maxVal){
        $("#my-div").children().css({
            "margin-left": tempLeftMargin            
        });

        endX = tempEndX;
        leftMargin = tempLeftMargin; 
    }     
  }

    function fingerDown(e){
      console.log("fingerdown "+e.originalEvent.touches.length);
      var fingersDown = e.originalEvent.touches.length;
      if (fingersDown > 1) {            
        toggleHammerScrolling(true);
      }else{
        startX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;        
      }
    }
```